# iTunes Connect: Invalid Swift Support - framework doesn’t have the correct file type for this location

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am currently upload my app on app store using Xcode 7.1.1

But when I upload my app, I received email from Apple.

```
Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "****".     
To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
Invalid Swift Support - The file     
****.app/Frameworks/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.framework, 
****.app/Frameworks/JLToast.framework, 
****.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework,         
****.app/Frameworks/JSQMessagesViewController.framework doesn’t have the
correct file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct
file,rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
Regards,
The App Store team
```

I'm Using Cocoapods. Here is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'TwinsChauffeur' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
use_frameworks! pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
use_frameworks! pod 'JLToast', '~> 1.3'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
use_frameworks! pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
pod 'IgaworksCore'
pod 'AdPopcornOfferwall'
end
```

and my project is Swift

also
pods framework name is red 
Is it usual?

[image: red framework image]

Answer (score 2):

solve myself.
It was so stupid.
After change product name only English.
solve all problems. 
And pod frameworks marked as red are normal thing.

Comment: Could you clarify your answer please?

Comment: Please tell us what you actually did. I am having the same problem.

Comment: I change product name to English In .plist

Comment: Its strange I am too getting this issue. But my product name is already in english.