# iTunes Store operation failed. Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am currently upload my app on app store using Xcode 8.2

But when I validate my app archive I got:

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
Invalid Swift Support. The file 
MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
...
MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib doesn’t have the correct file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file
rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode
and resubmit it.
```

I have checked 
[iTunes Connect: Invalid Swift Support - framework doesn’t have the correct file type for this location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969268/itunes-connect-invalid-swift-support-framework-doesn-t-have-the-correct-file)

- My application name/folder in english without spaces spec.chars etc.
- My xcode version 8.2
- My project on swift 3
- Enable bitcode - NO
- I'm using Pods